# Can my lost data on Sky Drive be restored?

Tags: onedrive

Microsoft just lost my data. I've had some problems with my ISP in the last days and the files I usually keep on Office weren't saved on the cloud but I thought that they were being stored locally because I had they saved before closing Word and Excel. Now all of the documents that I've edited during the last few days have lost all of their edits when I opened them. Is there any way to restore it? This is pretty infuriating. I'm on Win 8

Answer (score 0):

You may try running an undelete utility such as [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) on your system to see if you can recover any files.  You might be able to recover files locally from your Skydrive directory that were there locally, uploaded, then deleted locally.

As far as recovering anything from Skydrive, you're probably out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing just happened to me. It turns out that OneDrive has kept my original folder as 'read-only' and created a new folder with an identical name and file structure for syncing.

Look into your local drive and see if you could find your original folder and files.
Good luck!!!